# How to process columns of an SQLite table in Java android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update

I have an SQLite table like:

```
+---+-------------+----------------+
|_id| lap_time_ms |formatted_elapse|
+---+-------------+----------------+
| 1 |  5600       | 00:05.6        |
| 2 |  4612       | 00:04.6        |
| 3 |  4123       | 00:04.1        |
| 4 |  15033      | 00:15.0        |
| 5 |  4523       | 00:04.5        |
| 6 |  6246       | 00:06.2        |
```

Where lap_time_ms is an of the type long and represents the amount of time in milliseconds for a lap while formatter_elapse is a String that represents the formatted (displayable) form of the first column (elapse).

My **question** is that if I want to add (say) 5 seconds (5000) to each lap_time_ms then I use a statement like:

```
DB.execSQL("update table_name set KEY_ELAPSE=KEY_ELAPSE+5000);
```

Which works fine however the **problem** is that formatted_elapse still retains its outdated value!

So, what is the best way to update the values in the formatted_elapse column if I have a function like:

```
public static String getFormattedTime(long milliseconds) {
    // custom code that processes the long
    return processedString;
}
```

It may be a *long* shot (metaphorically speaking of course ;) but is it possible to have SQLite link the two columns such that if I update a lap_time_ms row, the formatted_elapse will automatically update appropriately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, it would be possible to create [a trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to update that column, but only if the formatting can be done with some [built-in SQLite function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) (Android does not allow user-defined functions):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_formatted_elapse
AFTER UPDATE OF lap_time_ms ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET formatted_elapse = strftime('%M:%f', NEW.lap_time_ms, 'unixepoch')
    WHERE _id = NEW._id;
END;
```

However, it would be bad design to store the formatted string in the database; it would be duplicated information that is in danger of becoming inconsistent.

Drop the `formatted_elapse` column and just call `getFormattedTime` in your code whenever you need it.

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware of SQLite triggers! It occurred to me that keeping the string was a possible vulnerability but I thought that not keeping it could mean a performance issue since the ListView associated with it would have to constantly format it as the user scrolls through it. However it is a small price to pay. Thanks!